# How to Read number from text file without whitespace in C++

Tags: c++, file, vector

I have a text file , which reads this.

`1101000`.

When I am trying to read this using

```
vector<int> arr;
int number;  //Variable to hold each number as it is read`
  ifstream in("input.txt",ios::in);
     while (in >> number) {
      arr.push_back(number);
   }
```

The program runs and shows `prg.exe` stops working and does not show any output.

However, giving space in between the integers , the same program runs and outputs correctly.

But I need to read the files without giving spaces in between.

Comment: Just check if there is a `newline` at the end of the file.

Comment: Where number is defined? Can you provide an extract from your input file?

Comment: Also, change the question tag. You added the `python` tag instead of the `C++` tag

Comment: Its just a one line string.
No new line nothing.
1101000

Comment: @agamagarwal Any solution to it?

Comment: declare number as a char if you only want to read one digit at a time. then convert to int and add to your vector like arr.push_back(number - '0');

Comment: If you are allowed to edit the file, try adding a newline in the end.
If not, you may consider reading the file character by character.

Comment: Can you write a bit of code? 
The two lines how to read the integers in an array 'arr'.
such that, arr[0]=1, arr[1]=1.arr[2]=0 and so on.
@samgak

Comment: @agamagarwal: there's no way this has anything to do with newlines...

Comment: @DipayanDev: the general idea on SO is someone here tells you what you're doing wrong and points you in the right direction, then you have a crack at coding something better.  samgak's advice is sound: try it.

Comment: @TonyD Thank! Samgak's advice works well!